# How to add parent directory to git repo

Tags: git

I am brand new to git so go easy. I have a project with the following structure:

```
~/proj
~/proj/dir1
~/proj/dir2
```

I created a git repo (on Bitbucket) and I want to import all of proj/ into the repo (including proj). What is the right way to do this? All instructions I find tell you to `cd proj/; git init . ; git add *;` This will add each of the subdirectories (dir1, dir2) to the repo but does not add proj. How do I add proj and it's subdirectories?

I was always able to do this in subversion but can't figure it out with git. Ideally when someone clones the project they will get proj/ and all of its subdirectories.

Comment: You cannot add the parent directory, but you can create a new directory and move all directories in that one (be sure not to move the .git directory nor the .gitignore file).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your repository should only contain the `proj` folder with nothing else at the same level, then the proper way to do it is to make `proj` the repository. You do that by following those instructions, i.e. calling `git init` within the `proj` folder.

That way, when people clone your repository, they automatically get a folder with the same name as the repository which then contains all the stuff. For example:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.com/username/proj
```

This will automatically create a folder `proj` in which the repository contents are being placed. If you had everything in another subfolder now, they would have to `cd proj/proj` to actually get there. That’s why you probably shouldn’t add another directory level there.

However, if you want other folders in the repository beside `proj` (at the same level), then it might make sense to make the parent folder a repository and add the folders there. Note though, that usually, you would want to make *one* repository *for each* separate project. So if you have `proj` and `proj2`, you should make two repositories that each contain one project.

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you. I did not want to have proj/proj on local disk, but I wanted to make sure when someone checked out the code they had proj/. By naming the repo proj/ I will accomplish all of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create a new parent directory and move your other directories:

```
$ mkdir parent
$ mv dir1 dir2 dir3 parent
$ git rm -r dir1 dir2 dir3
$ git add parent/*
```

Then check using `git status`.

Answer (score 1):

Create the parent directory. Use `git mv` to move the folders into the parent directoy